# Catch Exception in ContextManager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Is it possible to catch an exception in a context manager?

Background: The method `get_data_from_remote_system()` connects to a remote system every five minutes and fetches data.

Sometimes the network is down.

I want to suppress the exception message for 30 minutes. After 30 minutes I want to see the exception.

I don't want to catch all exception. Just some. In this case `socket.timeout`.

Is there a way to write a contact-manager which implements this and the resulting usage of this context-manager looks like this?

```
with suppress_exception(exceptions=[socket.timeout], minutes=30):
    get_data_from_remote_system()
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. This (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006095/tidying-up-series-of-try-except-statements/53006381#53006381} came up earlier this week. It doesn't answer your question completely but is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was not aware that if you return `True` in `__exit__()`, then the exception does not get raised.

Now `suppress_exception()` context-manager is easy:

```
class suppress_exception(object):
    def __init__(self, exceptions_to_catch, minutes=30):
        self.exceptions_to_catch = exceptions_to_catch
        self.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes)
        code = sys._getframe().f_back.f_code
        self.cache_key = 'suppress_exception_' + code.co_filename + str(sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        datetime_of_first_failure = cache.get(self.cache_key)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not type:
            cache.delete(self.cache_key)
            if datetime_of_first_failure:
                logging.info('Fine again. First failure was %s. Duration (first failure until ok): %s' % (
                    datetime_of_first_failure, now - datetime_of_first_failure))
            return
        if not issubclass(type, self.exceptions_to_catch):
            # Thils will raise an exception
            return
        if not datetime_of_first_failure:
            cache.set(self.cache_key, now)
            datetime_of_first_failure = now
        log_method = logging.warn
        if datetime_of_first_failure + self.timedelta > now:
            log_method = logging.info
        log_method('%s %s (datetime_of_first_failure=%s)' % (type.__name__, value, datetime_of_first_failure))
        return True
```

Comment: Nevertheless I think this use case is not nice. The code should do what the code should do and fail. It is the work of a higher level to suppress exceptions for some time. The code should not get altered. A log- or server monitor should handle this.